# AWS-CDK : Cross reference stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to write a code in aws-cdk (Python) to build an infrastructure. I need to deploy a CloudFront Distribution (Stack-A) in one AWS account. Then, I need to create some DNS records for this distribution (Stack-B) in another AWS account. I have two stacks for each account in the same CDK app. I'm getting this error ' "Stack-A" cannot consume a cross reference from stack "Stack-B". Cross stack references are only supported for stacks deployed to the same environment or between nested stacks and their parent stack'.

Can someone suggest a solution to solve this issue, please?

The code looks like below.

```
prod = core.Environment(account = "111111111111", region = "us-east-1")
dev = core.Environment(account = "222222222222", region = "us-east-1")

app = core.App()

s3_stack = A (app, "Stack-A", env = dev)
dist = s3_stack.dist_target
dns_lookup_stack = B (app, "Stack-B", env = prod, distribution = dist)

app.synth()




class A(core.Stack):

def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, id, env = dev)

    # Create Origin Access Identity.
    self.cloudfrontOAI = _cf.OriginAccessIdentity(
        self,
        "cloudfrontOAI",
        comment = "cdk-OAI",
    )

    # Create S3 bucket.
    self.bucket = _s3.Bucket(self, id + "_s3-bucket",
        bucket_name = ('dev-cdk-website'),
        block_public_access = _s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
        removal_policy = core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY)

    # Add bucket policy
    self.bucket.add_to_resource_policy(
        _iam.PolicyStatement(
            sid = "Grant Cloudfront Origin Access Identity to list S3 bucket.",
            actions = ["s3:ListBucket"],
            resources = [self.bucket.bucket_arn],
            principals = [self.cloudfrontOAI.grant_principal]
        )
    )
    # Get the hosted zone details. For example, from the production Route-53 service.
    self.hosted_zone = _route53.HostedZone.from_hosted_zone_attributes(
        self,
        "Existing_production_zone",
        hosted_zone_id  = zone_id,
        zone_name = zone_name
    )

    self.cert = _acm.Certificate(
        self,
        "cert",
        domain_name = website_name,
        subject_alternative_names = [],
        validation = _acm.CertificateValidation.from_dns(hosted_zone = self.hosted_zone)
    )
            
    # CloudFront Source Configuration
    source_config = _cf.SourceConfiguration(
        s3_origin_source = _cf.S3OriginConfig(
            s3_bucket_source = self.bucket,
            origin_access_identity = self.cloudfrontOAI,
        ),
       
        behaviors = [
            _cf.Behavior(
                is_default_behavior = True,
            )
        ],
    )

    # CloudFront error configuration settings
    error_config = _cf.CfnDistribution.CustomErrorResponseProperty(
        error_code = 404,
        error_caching_min_ttl=300,
        response_code=404,
        response_page_path = "/404.html"
    )

    # Certificate configuration settings for CF Distribution.
    cert_config = _cf.ViewerCertificate.from_acm_certificate(self.cert,
        aliases = [],
        security_policy = _cf.SecurityPolicyProtocol.TLS_V1_2_2019,
        ssl_method = _cf.SSLMethod.SNI
    )
        
    # Create cloud front distribution.     
    self.dist = _cf.CloudFrontWebDistribution(
        self,
        "staticsitedist",
        origin_configs = [source_config],
        comment = "dev--cdk-website",
        price_class = _cf.PriceClass("PRICE_CLASS_ALL"),
        error_configurations = [error_config],
        viewer_certificate = cert_config
        )       
    self.dist_target = _route53_targets.CloudFrontTarget(self.dist)
```

class B(core.Stack):

```
def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, id, env = prod)

    self.dist_target = kwargs["distribution"]

    self.hosted_zone = _route53.HostedZone.from_lookup(
        self,
        "Existing_production_zone",
        domain_name = domain_name,
    )

    # Export Zone_ID
    self.zone_id = core.CfnOutput(
        self,
        "zone_id",
        value = self.hosted_zone.hosted_zone_id,
        description = "Zone Id for the given domain name",
        export_name = "zoneId"
    )

    # Export Zone Name
    self.zone_name = core.CfnOutput(
        self,
        "zone_name",
        value = self.hosted_zone.zone_name,
        description = "zone name for the given domain name",
        export_name = "zoneName"
    )

    # Add A Records to DNS.
    self.ARecord = _route53.ARecord(
        self,
        "ARecord",
        record_name = website_name,
        target = _route53.AddressRecordTarget.from_alias(self.dist_target),
        zone = self.hosted_zone
    )
```

Comment: can you share some code. without looking at the code, all i can think is exporting cloudfront distribution url from stackA and set the exported value to a namespace variable, so that you can use it in the subsequent step

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for getting back to me. I have added the code to the post.

Comment: thanks. this line must be returning the cloudfront url `_route53.AddressRecordTarget.from_alias(self.dist_target),` . i think you just need the cloudfront url to be exported from the first stack and import it in the second stack